# Algorithm to get all zeniths crossing a box in three dimensions, MATLAB implementation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, multidimensional-array, geometry

I have a 3D geometry problem and I am not certain of the best approach to solve it. I have a model with two boxes, one above the others. They have the same dimension, L (length) * p (depth) * e (thickness), and are separated by a height of h. They are perfectly superposed, with no offset between them.

For each point of my bottom box, I want to get the zenith of *all* lines that can cross the top box and arrive to this point. It doesn't matter if the line crosses the top box by the top or the side.

The zenith is the angle of "looking up". In our case, a zenith of 0 represents the point directly above the point P, and an angle of 90 is directly looking in front. A zenith of 180 would be looking below the point, but for our use, it's useless. The zeniths we look for are between 0 and 90°.

For a more intuitive visualization, let's say that I have a hole in the ceiling, and that I want to map the zenith of all light that crosses this hole and reaches the floor.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Diagram of two boxes with lines crossing the top box to reach the bottom box]

For any point P of the bottom box, I want an array containing the zeniths of all "rays" that cross the top box before arriving on P. The red lines are the "edges", the last zeniths I would get for each corner.

I am working on a way to code it in MATLAB and I was wondering if there was a better algorithm that I am not seeing. My approach, in pseudocode, would be this:

```
bottomBox = [1:L, 1:p, 1:e];
topBox = [1:L, 1:p, 1+h:e+h];


results = zeros(L:p) * NaN; % Array of results, one per "case" on the bottom box
zeniths = zeros(L:p) * NaN; % Array of zeniths for each result case

for i = 1:L
    for j = 1:p      % Browsing the bottom box case by case
        for k = 1:L
           for l = 1:p 
               for m = 1:e    % For each bottom box case, browsing the top box case by case
                   p1 = topBox(k,l,m);     % p1 is each case on the top box
                   p2 = bottomBox(i,j,1);  % p2 is the current bottom box case, z doesn't mattter
                   p3 = topBox(i,j,m);     % p3 is the projection of p2 on the top box (zenith = 0)

                   v1 = p1 - p2;
                   v2 = p3 - p2;

                   zeniths(k,l) = rad2deg(atan2(norm(cross(p1, p2)), dot(p1, p2)));
               end
            end
         end
         results(i,j) = zeniths;
     end
end
```

I tried to implement this and I couldn't get it to work. More specifically, the angle calculation doesn't seem to work, I have an error stating:

> Error using cross;
> A and B must be of length 3 in the dimension in which the cross product is taken.

I am looking for advice on how to build the algorithm.

Please tell me if the question is better suited for another StackExchange community, such as Math.

Comment: Sorry but what do you want to get? What are `zeniths`? Just angles? From vertical axis?

Comment: The documentation for [`cross`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cross.html) specifies: "If A and B are vectors, then they must have a length of 3. If A and B are matrices or multidimensional arrays, then they must have the same size. In this case, the cross function treats A and B as collections of three-element vectors. The function calculates the cross product of corresponding vectors along the first array dimension whose size equals 3." I don't know what your `p1` and `p2` look like but they **must** have one of their dimension = 3.

Comment: On a more general view, your problem seems highly symetrical, you could just solve it for a quarter of your points `p` on the bottom plane, then mirror once over the `x` axis, then mirror the whole lot again against the `y` axis`. You'll save a lot of computation this way.

Comment: @MBo, yes, sorry about that. I will edit the question to specify it. Angles from 0 to 90° (or from 0 to pi/2 radians). Basically, for each point, we look around on the horizontal axis (the azimuth angle), and up and down (the zenith angle). What I'm looking for is, for a point, for every azimuth, every zenith.

Comment: @Hoki very good point, I'll keep it in mind during optimization

Comment: @Hoki also regardinig cross, thank you. I will look into another way to get the angle between 3 3D points.

Comment: Also for simplifying computations, you do not need to bother with the thickness of your plates, just consider the problem between 2 planes:  the top face of the bottom plate and the bottom face of the top plate. (you can add the thickness in your model later if it requires it, but this specific computation doesn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get you started showing you one way to do it for 1 point and I'll let you build the final loop to do the calc for all your points.

As expressed in the comment, for the purpose of these calculations, you do not need to consider the thickness of your plates, you can model them simply with two parallel planes separated by a distance `H`.

I don't know the size of your plates nor the grid size you want so I'll keep it simple for this example:

```
H = 5 ; % distance between the planes

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:3,-2:2) ;
GridSize = size(X) ;
Zb = zeros(GridSize) ;
Zt = zeros(GridSize) + H ;
```

This gives you 4 matrices, defining 2 planes. The bottom plane is composed of `[X,Y,Zb]` and the top plane is formed by `[X,Y,Zt]`.

If you want to visualise them, you can run the following code (optional):

```
%% Display planes
figure ;
ht = surf(X,Y,Zt, 'FaceColor',[.8 .8 .8],'DisplayName','Top plate') ;
hold on
hb = surf(X,Y,Zb, 'FaceColor',[.6 .6 .6],'DisplayName','Bottom plate') ;
xlabel('X') ; ylabel('Y') ; zlabel('Z') ;
axis equal ; legend show
```

[image: Two parallel planes]

---

Now for the rest of the example, I selected a point `P`, at coordinate `[-2,1,0]`. This choice is completely arbitrary, just for the example. In your final algorythm you will still have to loop over several points `Pi` (although remember that your problem is symetric so if your domain is too large you can reduce your computations by using the symetries of your model).

```
%% This will have to be embedded into a loop over the points Pi
% Assuming points P=(-2,1,0)
p = [-2;1;0] ;

zn = [0;0;1] ; % unitary vector, oriented Oz

dx = X - p(1) ; % `x` distance between all points of the plane and P
dy = Y - p(2) ; % `y` distance between all points of the plane and P
dz = zeros(size(X)) + H ;   % `z` distance (all the same)
V = [dx(:) dy(:) dz(:)].' ; % to obtain list of vector V = [dx;dy;dz] ;

nv = size(V,2) ;            % number of points/angle to calculate
zenith = zeros(nv,1) ;      % preallocate result matrix (always good!)
for k=1:nv
    % [u] is the vector going from `P` to the current point considered on the top plane
    u = V(:,k) ; 
    % determine the angle between [u] and [zn]
    zenith(k) = atan2( norm(cross(u,zn)) , dot(u,zn) ) ;
end
% Reshape "zenith" from vector to matrix so it matches the base grid system
zenith = reshape( zenith , GridSize ) ;
```

You now have, for this point `P`, a matrix of angle with every other point of the top plane:

```
>> rad2deg(zenith)
ans =
         32.31         30.96         32.31         35.80         40.32         45.00         49.39
         24.09         21.80         24.09         29.50         35.80         41.81         47.12
         15.79         11.31         15.79         24.09         32.31         39.51         45.56
         11.31             0         11.31         21.80         30.96         38.66         45.00
         15.79         11.31         15.79         24.09         32.31         39.51         45.56
```

Once again, completely optionally, if you want to visualise the vectors which were used for the calculations:

```
for k=1:nv
    hp(k) = plot3([p(1) X(k)],[p(2) Y(k)],[0 H],'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','k') ;
end
```

will yield:

[image]

---

Now for your final result, remember you have a 2D matrix **for each** point `P` of your bottom plane, so your final result will either be a collection of 2D matrices or a large 3D matrix.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you very much! This seems to be exactly what I need. I am going to try around a bit and will validate the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Zenith angle is just

```
atan2(h, sqrt(dx^2+dy^2))
```

where `dx, dy` are coordinate differences along `L` and `p` axes (`i-k` and `j-l` in your loops)

Perhaps `h+m` (`m` as your variable `for m = 1:e`) instead of `h` if you need points inside top box

Comment: I think in MATLAB the function [`atan2()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html) is preferable for angle determination, your example  would become: `atan2(h,sqrt(dx^2+dy^2))`

Comment: @Hoki OK, you are right. While result domain of `atan` looks more suitable for zenit angle,  always positive sqrt provides same range with atan2, but atan2 gives valid vertical Pi/2 angle